# How to deal with a lot of table layout in single activity?

Tags: android

Actually, 1 table layout contain about 12 rows and 10 column. So what I do is using setvisible to hide table layout when displaying other table layout.

The reason I put a lot of table layout in 1 activity is that it will use the same method in the activity. I already planning to use 1 activity for 1 table layout to easier maintain the code. But when I do this I need to deal with the global method which makes me feels very complicated.

Is there any idea to solve my problem?Or should I continue to use setvisible to hide the activity?

2 tablelayout consist of 3k code. Link in gist: https://gist.github.com/zawawimanja/e7baf0f60db35e5f6e4bb562b52428c2
It is a massive length. So what if I have 12 tablelayout in 1 activity?

Comment: can't you use gridview ?

Comment: @VivekMishra no. The best way is using table row consist 12 row and 10 column.

Comment: @VivekMishra this is link gist https://gist.github.com/zawawimanja/e7baf0f60db35e5f6e4bb562b52428c2 . 2 tablelayout.